# Any engine that can play like Petrosian?

Tags: engines, positional-play, famous-players

So, I am a big big fan of Petrosian and his Style. I tried to search for engines that can actually try to imitate it's style, instead I found Tal's engine (Opental 1.1). Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think chessmaster software has a Petrosian style.

Comment: You can have engines that claim to imitate player X but I don't think you can't find any that is successful at it

Comment: Place a - before all parameters of Opental? :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ShashChess](https://github.com/amchess/ShashChess) which is a Stockfish derivative has a `Petrosian` UCI option which you can use to make the engine play in a similar style to Petrosian. There're also options for Tal and Capablanca, moreover you can mix these options (e.g. Tal+Capablanca). Read more here in the documentation: https://github.com/amchess/ShashChess#shashin-section

Answer (score 1):

Avataruci.org has an interesting way to mimic your own style. You can get all of your games in one pgn and upload it, get a weight file and run the with their engine. It will try to imitate your style. Similarly, download Petrosian's games from pgnmentor and try doing it (I think they already have his weight file in their website, you just have to download it from there).

Answer (score 0):

You can use Rybka chess engine, his skills are similar to Petrossian style.